# Changing column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have the following dataset that I want to clean up:

```
              Provice      Lat     Long Date Recovered
Anhui.1         Anhui  31.8257 117.2264    1         0
Chongqing.1 Chongqing  30.0572 107.8740    1         0
Guangdong.1 Guangdong  23.3417 113.4244    1         0
Henan.1         Henan 33.88202 113.6140    1         0
Hubei.1         Hubei  30.9756 112.2707    1        28
Hunan.1         Hunan  27.6104 111.7088    1         0
Jiangsu.1     Jiangsu  32.9711 119.4550    1         0
Jiangxi.1     Jiangxi   27.614 115.7221    1         0
Shandong.1   Shandong  36.3427 118.1498    1         0
Zhejiang.1   Zhejiang  29.1832 120.0934    1         0
Anhui.2         Anhui  31.8257 117.2264    2         0
Chongqing.2 Chongqing  30.0572 107.8740    2         0
Guangdong.2 Guangdong  23.3417 113.4244    2         2
Henan.2         Henan 33.88202 113.6140    2         0
Hubei.2         Hubei  30.9756 112.2707    2        28
Hunan.2         Hunan  27.6104 111.7088    2         0
Jiangsu.2     Jiangsu  32.9711 119.4550    2         0
Jiangxi.2     Jiangxi   27.614 115.7221    2         0
Shandong.2   Shandong  36.3427 118.1498    2         0
Zhejiang.2   Zhejiang  29.1832 120.0934    2         0
```

What I want to do is change the Provice column so that instead of it reading "Anhui.1   Anhui" it simply reads "Anhui" (and similar for the rest of the values under Provice. Also, I would like to associate an actual date for each value under the Date column. For instance if there is a value 1 under Date then I would like it to read 20-01-22 and if there is a value 2 under Date then read 20-01-23.

Essentially, I would like my dataset to look like this:

```
  Provice      Lat     Long      Date   Recovered
Anhui      31.8257 117.2264    20-01-22         0
Chongqing  30.0572 107.8740    20-01-22         0
Guangdong  23.3417 113.4244    20-01-22         0
Henan     33.88202 113.6140    20-01-22         0
Hubei      30.9756 112.2707    20-01-22        28
Hunan      27.6104 111.7088    20-01-22         0
Jiangsu    32.9711 119.4550    20-01-22         0
Jiangxi     27.614 115.7221    20-01-22         0
Shandong   36.3427 118.1498    20-01-22         0
Zhejiang   29.1832 120.0934    20-01-22         0
Anhui      31.8257 117.2264    20-01-23         0
Chongqing  30.0572 107.8740    20-01-23         0
Guangdong  23.3417 113.4244    20-01-23         2
Henan     33.88202 113.6140    20-01-23         0
Hubei      30.9756 112.2707    20-01-23        28
Hunan      27.6104 111.7088    20-01-23         0
Jiangsu    32.9711 119.4550    20-01-23         0
Jiangxi     27.614 115.7221    20-01-23         0
Shandong   36.3427 118.1498    20-01-23         0
Zhejiang   29.1832 120.0934    20-01-23         0
```

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: it seems to me that your problem is the row names row.names(your_dataframe)<-NULL

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to strip off the first component of the name, then use `sub`:

```
Provice <- c("Anhui.1         Anhui", "Chongqing.1 Chongqing", "Guangdong.1 Guangdong")
out <- sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", Provice)
out

[1] "Anhui"     "Chongqing" "Guangdong"
```

The regex pattern `^\S+s+` will match the first term along with following whitespace, which then is removed by the replacement empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
df <- `rownames<-`(within(df,Date <- format(as.Date("20-01-22","%y-%m-%d")+Date,"%y-%m-%d")),NULL)
```

such that

```
> df
     Provice      Lat     Long     Date Recovered
1      Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-22         0
2  Chongqing 30.05720 107.8740 20-01-22         0
3  Guangdong 23.34170 113.4244 20-01-22         0
4      Henan 33.88202 113.6140 20-01-22         0
5      Hubei 30.97560 112.2707 20-01-22        28
6      Hunan 27.61040 111.7088 20-01-22         0
7    Jiangsu 32.97110 119.4550 20-01-22         0
8    Jiangxi 27.61400 115.7221 20-01-22         0
9   Shandong 36.34270 118.1498 20-01-22         0
10  Zhejiang 29.18320 120.0934 20-01-22         0
11     Anhui 31.82570 117.2264 20-01-23         0
12 Chongqing 30.05720 107.8740 20-01-23         0
13 Guangdong 23.34170 113.4244 20-01-23         2
14     Henan 33.88202 113.6140 20-01-23         0
15     Hubei 30.97560 112.2707 20-01-23        28
16     Hunan 27.61040 111.7088 20-01-23         0
17   Jiangsu 32.97110 119.4550 20-01-23         0
18   Jiangxi 27.61400 115.7221 20-01-23         0
19  Shandong 36.34270 118.1498 20-01-23         0
20  Zhejiang 29.18320 120.0934 20-01-23         0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Provice = c("Anhui", "Chongqing", "Guangdong", 
"Henan", "Hubei", "Hunan", "Jiangsu", "Jiangxi", "Shandong", 
"Zhejiang", "Anhui", "Chongqing", "Guangdong", "Henan", "Hubei", 
"Hunan", "Jiangsu", "Jiangxi", "Shandong", "Zhejiang"), Lat = c(31.8257, 
30.0572, 23.3417, 33.88202, 30.9756, 27.6104, 32.9711, 27.614, 
36.3427, 29.1832, 31.8257, 30.0572, 23.3417, 33.88202, 30.9756, 
27.6104, 32.9711, 27.614, 36.3427, 29.1832), Long = c(117.2264, 
107.874, 113.4244, 113.614, 112.2707, 111.7088, 119.455, 115.7221, 
118.1498, 120.0934, 117.2264, 107.874, 113.4244, 113.614, 112.2707, 
111.7088, 119.455, 115.7221, 118.1498, 120.0934), Date = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Recovered = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Anhui.1", 
"Chongqing.1", "Guangdong.1", "Henan.1", "Hubei.1", "Hunan.1", 
"Jiangsu.1", "Jiangxi.1", "Shandong.1", "Zhejiang.1", "Anhui.2", 
"Chongqing.2", "Guangdong.2", "Henan.2", "Hubei.2", "Hunan.2", 
"Jiangsu.2", "Jiangxi.2", "Shandong.2", "Zhejiang.2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give your the names

```
library(DescTools)
a=StrPos(demo$Provice, pattern = "[0-9]")
np=data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
  np=rbind(substr(demo$Provice[i],a[i]+1,nchar(demo$Provice[i])),np)
  names(np)="Provice"
  np$Provice=as.character(np$Provice)
}
```

This should change your date to your req. Assuming you just have these two dates. Then you can format using as.Date.

```
df$date=ifelse(date==1,"20-01-22","20-01-23")
```

Answer (score -1):

Province<- stringi::stri_replace(Province,regex="\\.\\s?\\d\\D+","")

Answer (score -1):

Date<-make_date(2020,01,22) + days (Date)

Assuming that your starting date is 22nd Jan. You need install library lubridate in order to work this code.